# Storing output of shell script to variable

Tags: bash, command-substitution, github

I have read many threads on this topic, but none of the solutions have worked for me.

I am trying to do the following:

```
RELEASE_COMMAND_OUTPUT=$(exec ~/temp/execs/github-release release --user patick --repo $REPO_NAME --tag $RELEASE_VERSION --name $RELEASE_VERSION --description "$DESC")
```

but the output of `./github-release` is not stored in the `RELEASE_COMMAND_OUTPUT` variable.

I'm aware of the concept of [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution), but none of the solutions I've tried have worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why the `exec`? Is the output of `github-release` written to standard output? What is the expected output (I'm not familiar with the `github-release` command and I can't find a manual for it)?

Comment: If the output you are seeking to store is being written to standard error rather than standard output, add `2>&1` to the end of your subshell and it too will be captured into the variable.

Comment: Is "--user patick" a typo in the question or a typo in the command? Could it be that you just get an error message in the latter case? What happens if you run the command (cut and paste please - do not retype) by itself, not in a command substitution? And as @DopeGothi indicates, if you redirect stdout, do you get anything? What value does `RELEASE_COMMAND_OUTPUT` get?

Comment: @DopeGhoti that works! I'm pulling the executable from another source, and I hadn't considered that it may be output to stderr rather than stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in your question's comments, the variable `RELEASE_COMMAND_OUTPUT` will only get the `STDOUT`[(standard output)](http://www.linfo.org/standard_output.html) of your command but not the `STDERR` [(standard error)](http://www.linfo.org/standard_error.html), as it seems to be your case.

When in doubt about the output of your command you can use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to [*mark the `STDERR` in red*](https://serverfault.com/questions/59262/bash-print-stderr-in-red-color) as in the following example:

```
command 2> >(while read line; do echo -e "\e[01;31m$line\e[0m" >&2; done)
```

Which is [redirecting](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) (the `2>` part) the `STDERR` of the `command` as input to the `while` block which will print it in red in the terminal.

You can also do the opposite, marking the `STDOUT` as red with:

```
command | grep .
```

Because grep act only in `STDOUT`

**NOTE**: in some systems you may need to [enable the color](https://superuser.com/questions/590723/grep-default-color-option) in grep using the flag `--color=auto`. On Macos and Linux usually it's enable by default.

Comment: The `grep` trick only works if your `grep` is configured to color matching lines, of course. It frequently is on Linux, but the idea will make no sense at all on platforms where it isn't.

Comment: Yes, macos enable colors by default. Anyway I added a note about the possibility of not enabled colors on some systems. Thank you!

Comment: The option might not even be available on some non-GNU platfoms but at least it's understandable now. I don't see why MacOS specifically is relevant here, though I suppose it completes the picture somewhat.

Comment: Macos is cited just as a flavor of Unix ;-)